# PDO Transaction rolling back when returning LastInsertID

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo, lastinsertid

I am having a strange problem which I don't understand. I have the following function which is supposed to return $asset_ID:

```
function commit_purchase($asset_type_ID, $org_ID, $asset_desc, $asset_cost, $date, $org_to_member_ID, $asset_ID, $purchaser_cur_invest, $purchaser_cred_deb, $purchaser_balance) {
global $db;
$db->beginTransaction();
$query = "INSERT INTO assets
                       (asset_type_ID, org_ID, asset_desc, asset_cost, asset_value, purchase_date, is_approved)
                    VALUES
                       (:asset_type_ID, :org_ID, :asset_desc, :asset_cost, :asset_cost, :date, 1)";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':asset_type_ID', $asset_type_ID);
$statement->bindValue(':org_ID', $org_ID);
$statement->bindValue(':asset_desc', $asset_desc);
$statement->bindValue(':asset_cost', $asset_cost);
$statement->bindValue(':date', $date);
$statement->execute();
$asset_ID = $db->lastInsertId();
//return $asset_ID;
$db->commit(); 
}
```

I am calling the function like so:

```
$asset_ID = commit_purchase($asset_type_ID, $org_ID..etc, etc.);
```

If I uncomment the `return $asset_ID`, the transaction rolls back and does not commit. If I leave it commented, the variable is not passed. If I comment out the `beginTransaction` and `commit` lines, I can uncomment the return `$asset_ID` and everything works.

I want it to stay as a transaction and I want to return the `$asset_ID`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `return $asset_ID;` line to after the commit as the execution of the function stops when you `return`. Without the commit being called you get an implicit rollback.

Comment: That did the trick. I plan on throwing in a few more queries before the commit. Will I be able to use the $asset_ID variable in the queries which follow?

Comment: Yes. Once you have assigned the variable it is available to use within the current scope unless you overwrite or unset it. You must not return the value until after you have executed all your queries and committed them.